# Display first and third value foreach array

Tags: php, arrays

I have several arrays stored in a variable. My variable holds these arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => firstname [1] => lastname [2] => email [3] => phone ) 
Array ( [0] => Benny [1] => Mose [2] => benny@mose.dk [3] => 12345678 ) 
Array ( [0] => Luke [1] => Skywalker [2] => luke@theforce.dk [3] => 10000000 ) 
Array ( [0] => Master [1] => Yoda [2] => yoda@theforce.dk [3] => 13370002 ) 
Array ( [0] => Ben [1] => Kenobi [2] => ben@theforce.dk [3] => 13370004 ) 
Array ( [0] => Darth [1] => Bandon [2] => darth@sith.dk [3] => 55554444 ) 
Array ( [0] => C-3PO [1] => Robot [2] => c-3po@theforce.dk [3] => 33339999 ) 
Array ( [0] => R2D2 [1] => Robot [2] => r2d2@theforce.dk [3] => 44447777 ) 
Array ( [0] => Han [1] => Solo [2] => han@frozen4life.dk [3] => 99998888 ) 
Array ( [0] => Jar jar [1] => Binks [2] => jarjar@theforce.dk [3] => 111112222 )
```

I want to display the first[0] and third[2] value for every array.

I'm able to display the first value for each array by using:

```
$CSVfp = fopen("csv-list.csv", "r");
if($CSVfp !== FALSE) {
 while(! feof($CSVfp)) {
  $data = fgetcsv($CSVfp);

echo '<hr>';
foreach($data as $arr)
{
    echo $data[0].' '.$data[1].', '.$data[2].'<br>'; // first element

}

 }
}
fclose($CSVfp);
```

But I can't figure out how to display both first and third value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple foreach loop should do the trick:

```
foreach($data as $arr)
{
    echo $arr[0]."\r\n"; // first element
    echo $arr[2]."\r\n"; // third element.
}
```

In a foreach loop, you take each element (in your case which i already an array) and can use it as whatever it is.

So in the first loop, `$arr` can be seen as:

```
Array ( [0] => firstname [1] => lastname [2] => email [3] => phone )
```

So you display the elements as normal.

You could do a second foreach loop if you wanted to display every second element in an array with dozens of elements, or search for particular elements or whatever:

```
foreach($data as $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
    {
        echo ($key=='someElement')?$val:"";
    }
}
```

Edit: Based on your comment, the variable doesn't in fact hold (all the) arrays you showed in your question, but rather only one of them at a time.

Based on that, you can simply access each element of the array:

```
echo $data[0]."\r\n"; // first element
echo $data[2]."\r\n"; // third element.
```

Edit 2:

```
$CSVfp = fopen("csv-list.csv", "r");
if($CSVfp !== FALSE) 
{
    while(! feof($CSVfp)) 
    {
        $data = fgetcsv($CSVfp);
        echo '<hr>';
        echo $data[0].' '.$data[1].', '.$data[2].'<br>'; // first element
    }
}
fclose($CSVfp);
```

You don't need a foreach at all - you are already accessing each row as a single simple array.

Edit 3:

You can use a simple counter and the modulus function:

```
$i=0;
$CSVfp = fopen("csv-list.csv", "r");
if($CSVfp !== FALSE) 
{
    while(! feof($CSVfp)) 
    {
        $i++;
        $data = fgetcsv($CSVfp);
        if($i%3==0)
        {
            echo '<hr>';
            echo $data[0].' '.$data[1].', '.$data[2].'<br>'; // first element
        }
    }
}
fclose($CSVfp);
```

Comment: Following your advice I tried using the simple the foreach loop. But it displays the first and third character of each value. E.g. firstname = fr and so on.

Comment: Thanks you were right. But now every entry is displayed 4 times. E.g. Firstname Firstname Firstname Firstname - that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It seems that it is inside another loop that isn't shown in your question. Are you iterating through a loop of database query results?

Comment: I'm retrieving the data from a CSV file inside a while loop. See edit.

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to ommit the first array and only display every third array?

Comment: @KarstenTietje See edit 3. I think that will work, I normally access the filesystem differently, but I would hazzard that will do the trick.

Comment: You sir are awesome. I knew i had to use a counter for this purpose, but I couldn't get it right. You made my day!

Comment: Thanks mate, I like to help out folks where I can - and a surprising amount of the time I find that I can learn something along the way. Wins for all :)